# Srv service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service

I am failing to turn on File and printer sharing on my Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition. Drilling down into the issue at hand I found that the following services were failing to start:

- Computer Browser
- Server

On attempting to start the Server service manually the following message was returned on Windows System log file:

> The Server service depends on the following service: Srv. This
>   service might not be installed

Querying the service status as follows:

```
sc query srv
```

Returned:

> The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

I have tried the following to remedy this problem:

```
sfc /scannow
```

which returned no errors.

I have run and applied latest Windows updates.
I have scanned the server for viruses and malware.

I have also run `netsh advfirewall reset`

None of the above attempts resolved the problem.

Copying srv.sys file from a good  running server also proved to be a challenge as the server stopped responding. I had to copy back the original srv.sys file.

And the problem persists. I have run out of ideas I just need someone to point me in the right direction. The server can not be formatted since it's in a production environment.

sincerely appreciate your insights.

Comment: **I think it's driver not service.** On my system (which is client-Vista not S2008R2) lanmanserver shows dependent on srv, and that on srv2 and that on srvnet, all with computer icons not 2-gear icons, and `sc query[ex]` _does_ list them as `TYPE: 2 FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER` rather than any of the types used for services. I also see them in `msinfo32` in `Software Environment` under `System Drivers` and _not_ under `Services`. I don't see how that points to any fix, however.

Comment: Dave, actually you are right. I traced it from the registry settings to srv.sys file under windows -system32 - drivers folder. I am attempting an offline repair of Windows Server installation to see if that will remedy the problem.Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

A service has a display name, and an actual name.
In this case, "Server" is the display name, "Lanmanserver" is the actual name. You need to the actual name with SC.EXE, so try

```
SC.EXE query lanmanserver

SERVICE_NAME: lanmanserver
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Also check the PATH environmental variable for invalid drives and remove them, or apply the hotfix described here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2316513

> > On a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, you have a volume that is referenced in the PATH system-environment variable. If the volume is inaccessible, the Lanmanserver service does not start after you restart the computer or after you stop and then restart the service manually. Additionally, event ID 7023 is logged in the System log.

[image]

Comment: Hi Craig620, Thank you kindly for your insight. I had already queried the  lanmanserver service. It is in stopped state because it depends on the srv service which has a problem.The idea here is resolve the srv service.

Answer (score 0):

For file and print sharing follow the below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltDTXqiASlc&app=desktop

Below is the syntax for Computer browser service:-

sc query browser.

sc start browser

net start browser

Comment: Thank you for your response sairam. I have already queried the browser service. It is in stopped state.  It can not start because it depends on the Server 'lanmanserver' service. The Server service can not start because it depends on the 'srv' service which appears not to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I ran `sc.exe config srvnet start= auto` it stated:

```
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

When I looked in registry there were two `ImagePath`:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\srvnet]
"Group"="Network"
"ImagePath"=hex(2):53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,44,00,\
  52,00,49,00,56,00,45,00,52,00,53,00,5c,00,73,00,72,00,76,00,6e,00,65,00,74,\
  00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"ImagePath"=hex(2):53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,44,00,\
  52,00,49,00,56,00,45,00,52,00,53,00,5c,00,73,00,72,00,76,00,6e,00,65,00,74,\
  00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"Start"=dword:00000003
"Type"=dword:00000002
"DisplayName"=""
```

So I deleted the whole `srvnet` key and imported reg from another computer (with only one `ImagePath`). And after reboot it started to work.

Don't know how could it be. Tried to create it with `regedit` and import above .reg back but couldn't.

Comment: it would be great, if you could show the difference between both

Comment: Between both what? ImagePaths are the same. And it is the only difference.

Comment: I meant, if you can show us the difference between non-working and working value?